# "Wrong type argument: commandp" error when binding a lambda to a key

Tags: emacs, command, key-bindings

I am getting a "Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda nil (forward-line 5))" here.

```
(global-set-key [?\M-n] (lambda () (forward-line 5)))
```

What is the error? I'm fairly sure it's simple & I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You're missing a closing parentheses. Probably not in your code though, only in the question.

Comment: As a side note: when you quote the anonymous function like that it won't be compiled. I imagine it's no big deal in your case, though.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`global-set-key` expects an interactive command. `(lambda () (interactive) (forward-line 5))` ought to work.

By the way, `C-h f commandp` is a pretty good starting point for errors like that.

Comment: I think there are no down sides. From the documentation:

>> The "call" to ‘interactive’ is actually a declaration rather than a
 function; it tells ‘call-interactively’ how to read arguments to pass
 to the function. When actually called, ‘interactive’ just returns
 nil.

Comment: So according to `(commandp)` documentation, lambda functions with top level call to `(interactive)` work, but how can I define a function with `(defun)` that would work?

Comment: peterhil: The commandp docs are just very specific, and its description does already cover what `defun` produces (which is a lambda expression assigned to the function cell of a symbol). As to your question, the only difference in syntax is wrt the name / lack thereof: substitute `defun foo` in place of `lambda` and you have yourself a named function instead of an anonymous one.  (And you *should* use named functions when binding keys in almost every instance.)

Answer (score 42):

The correct form should be this -

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") (lambda () (interactive) (forward-line 5)))
```

The problem was that you forgot to put `(interactive)` (as brendan mentioned).

By the way, you will notice that I used the `(kbd)` function for specifying the key-binding. That function is immensely useful since you can put the key-bindings almost literally.

Answer (score 2):

I've also seen this error on a new machine where I am using my usual `.emacs` file but haven't installed my packages, and the command to be executed is in one of those packages. (Because a command that can't be executed definitely isn't interactive!)

Answer (score 0):

providing a function defined with `defun` should work the same way as
a lambda, as long as it satisfies the same requirements.

So

```
(defun my-move-forward ()
 (interactive)
 (forward-line 5))
```

should work.