# Emacs setting key binding

Tags: emacs

I am trying to create a command which will allow to move other window up/down depending on keybinding I assigned to it:

So what I added to my .emacs:

```
(defun scroll-down-one-line ()                                                          
(scroll-other-window 1))                                                              

(global-set-key "\C-\M-v" 'scroll-down-one-line)
```

And it doesn't work :(
Says wrong type of argument
Can you suggest a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/error-in-emacs-elisp-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key).

```
(defun scroll-down-one-line ()
    (interactive)
    (scroll-other-window 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-v") 'scroll-down-one-line)
```

Specifically, you need the [`'interactive`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Interactive.html#Interactive) special form.