# Emacs Scheme evaluate-last-sexp

Tags: emacs, mit-scheme

I've tried to add these to my .emacs, but they seem to have no effect

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-e") 'scheme-send-last-sexp )
(local-set-key (kbd "C-M-x") 'scheme-send-definition )
```

I'm using quack and have the MIT-Scheme running in one buffer when I try C-x C-e in a .scm buffer. Instead of evaluating the last s-expression, I get "You must start an inferior LISP with run-ilisp." But then if I manually add the shortcuts:

```
M-x local-set-key RET C-x C-e scheme-send-last-sexp RET
M-x local-set-key RET C-M-x scheme-send-definition RET
```

It works. How can I get this functionality in Emacs (23.3.1) without manually entering it?

Answer (score 5):

### <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `local-set-key`

> local-set-key is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> (local-set-key KEY COMMAND)
>
> ...snip...
>
> The binding goes in the current buffer's local map,
>   which in most cases is shared with all other buffers in the same major mode.

So when you add `local-set-key` to your init file, the binding is made in
whatever major-mode is used while that file loads.

You need to add it to one specific major-mode.  To do this you need two pieces
of information:

1. The name of the major-mode.

   - Use <kbd>C-h v</kbd><kbd>major-mode</kbd> from a buffer with the major-mode already loaded.
   - Let's assume `mit-scm-mode`
   - Append `-map` to this to get the keymap.
2. The name of the file that defines the major-mode.

   - Use <kbd>C-h f</kbd><kbd>mit-scm-mode</kbd>.
   - Let's assume `mit-scm-mode.el`.
   - Use the file name with no extension.

With these, you would add:

```
(eval-after-load "mit-scm-mode"
  '(progn
     (define-key mit-scm-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-e") 'scheme-send-last-sexp )
     (define-key mit-scm-mode-map (kbd "C-M-x") 'scheme-send-definition )))
```

to your init file.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the great answer above, this is what I had to do with stock Emacs 26.1 on Debian 10 buster.

```
(eval-after-load "scheme"                                                                                                                         
  '(progn                                                                                                                                         
     (load "cmuscheme")                                                                                                                           
     (define-key scheme-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-e") (lambda () (interactive) (scheme-send-last-sexp)))                                               
     (define-key scheme-mode-map (kbd "C-M-x") (lambda () (interactive) (scheme-send-definition)))))
```

I worked it out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/wrong-type-argument-commandp-error-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key) and some digging around.