# wrong type argument commandp with a custom function in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I know this type of question have been asked by many people,
but I have read many similar posts and still have no idea
what to do. So here is the elisp code in .emacs:

```
;; send line to python console
(require 'python-mode)
(defun py-execute-line-down ()
  "execute python line and move cursor down"
  (progn
  (py-execute-line)
  (evil-next-line)))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda () (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'py-execute-line-down)))
```

I also tried to add `(interactive)` into the function, it didn't work.

Comment: For those interested in looking at the source code for `python-mode`, here is a link to library likely being used by the original poster:  https://launchpad.net/python-mode  The latest version has a green download link.

Comment: qed: `(interactive)` *is* all you need. I'm guessing that you didn't re-evaluate the function after adding that line? Or you put it in the wrong place? (should be immediately after the docstring). Also note that you also don't need to wrap `(progn ... )` around the body of a function.

Comment: Also: the call to `define-key` does not need to go in a hook, where it will be evaluated every time you open a python buffer.

Comment: +1 to @phils's comment. And make sure that you put `(interactive)` in the right place: after the doc string and before the function body.

Comment: Linking some similar questions: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/wrong-type-argument-commandp-error-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key?rq=1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077943/wrong-type-argument-on-an-emacs-function-ive-written) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173148/local-keymap-for-emacs-outline-minor-mode/17173469#17173469).

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep the record here, this seemed to do the trick, not sure if it's optimal though:

```
;; send line to python console
(require 'python-mode)
(defun py-execute-line-down ()
  "execute python line and move cursor down"
  (interactive)
  (py-execute-line)
  (evil-next-line 1))
(defun kaiyin-pykeys ()
  "python mode custome keys"
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c j") 'py-execute-line-down)
  )
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'kaiyin-pykeys)
```

Taking Dan's advice, I changed the above into:

```
;; send line to python console
(require 'python-mode)
(defun py-execute-line-down ()
  "execute python line and move cursor down"
  (interactive)
  (py-execute-line)
  (forward-line 1))
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c j") 'py-execute-line-down)
```

Comment: I'd suggest replacing `(evil-next-line 1)` with `(forward-line 1)` to avoid introducing an Evil dependency (on the off chance you decide to stop using the latter).  Presuming you want to bind `C-cj` in all python buffers, I'd also suggest dispensing with the second `defun` and `add-hook` combo and just put the following into your .emacs file: `(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c j") 'py-execute-line-down)`.