# Defining key binding with arguments

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to map C-f C-b as moving forward and backward by a fixed amount of lines in a file.

I did this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'next-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-b") 'previous-line)
```

but I don't know how to specify an argument before the `next-line` command. I guess I should use `digit-argument` but I am unable to write the command in a correct way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in emacs elisp when binding a lambda to a key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/error-in-emacs-elisp-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key)

Comment: ok this (global-set-key (kbd "C-f") '(lambda () (interactive) (forward-line 5))) works. 
Although it does not completely answer my question, how would I bind something like M-5 C-n or more complex macros without having to use lambda, I am probably missing something really basic on the working of elisp...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the possible alternatives would be define a new function:

```
(defun my-next-line ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line 5))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'my-next-line)
```

Otherwise, if it is just something you can accomplish with the keyboard you might want to use

```
M-x name-last-kbd-macro
```

and save it in your .emacs file

```
M-x insert-kbd-macro
```

and have emacs implement the function for you.
It will just get the name you gave in your call to name-last-kbd-macro

Comment: I did not know about the insert macro, this is very useful. Thank you

Comment: I've tried this with a string argument, in works but don't forget (as I did the first time) the quotes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 14):

You've changed your question to be about how to bind directly to key sequences

This binds <kbd>C-c l</kbd> to <kbd>C-u 5 C-n</kbd>

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") (kbd "C-u 5 C-n"))
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot for this hint.

Comment: This is an excellent way to add new keybindings, when you already aware of the keystrokes and removes the step for naming macro.