# local keymap for emacs outline-minor-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to set the **outline-minor-mode** for **init.el** file and when **TAB** key is pressed on the lines starting with **;** the function **outline-toggle-children** should be called in order to fold and expand the sub headings.

Below is the code for hook. But it does not work for the "TAB" key binding as expected.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
      (lambda ()           
        (if (equal (buffer-name) "init.el")
        (progn
          (outline-regexp "^;+")
          (outline-minor-mode 1)
          (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") ; this does not work
                 (lambda ()
                   (if (string-match outline-regexp (thing-at-point 'line))
                       (outline-toggle-children))))))))
```

Comment: I recommend you don't set `outline-regexp` and use its default value (which treats comments with 3 or more semi-colons as headings and top-level Lisp code as "subsubsubheadings").

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Wrong type argument: commandp" error when binding a lambda to a key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/wrong-type-argument-commandp-error-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the error you get is `wrong-type-argument commandp`.  This happens because functions bound to keys must be "interactive" functions.  You need to add an `(interactive)` declaration to the function, so that Emacs knows how to invoke the function in response to an event:

```
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (if (string-match outline-regexp (thing-at-point 'line))
       (outline-toggle-children)))
```