# Emacs compile ignoring compile-command variable

Tags: go, emacs

Initially, I had the following defined in my .emacs.d/init.el

```
(defun go-mode-setup ()
  (setq compile-command "go build -v && go test -v && go vet && golint")
  (define-key go-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'compile)
  )
```

While in go-mode, everything else seemed to work fine, but his did not seem to set or respect my C-c C-c command, instead producing

```
C-c C-c is undefined.
```

So, I added an explicit hook:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key go-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'compile)))
```

This now respects my C-c C-c kbd shortcut, but still ignores the compile-command I set.  Unfortunately, it seems to compile the entire folder rather than just the main.go file I am working on.

```
Compile command: make -k
```

How can I set C-c C-c to use the compile-command I set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me.  The only thing missing is an `add-hook`.  You probably want to set the `compile-command` to be buffer-local as well.

Here's my code that definitely works:

```
(defun jpk/go-mode-hook ()
  (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
  (setq compile-command "go build -v")
  (define-key go-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'compile))
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'jpk/go-mode-hook)
```

I strongly recommend against redefining `compile` like in @jdc's answer.  If you must define your own command, do it with a different name.

You may want to check out the [multi-compile](https://github.com/ReanGD/emacs-multi-compile) package, it allows you to set multiple compile commands (optionally major-mode specific).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (defun compile ()
    (setq compile-command "go build -v && go test -v && go vet && golint"))
  (define-key go-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'compile)))
```

Comment: Ah, Lost In Stupid Parenthesis.  Sorry if I missed one.

Comment: I got a weird "wrong argument type: commandp, compile" I was looking for whether I had a typo for command as commandp, but I think that is the name of a variable it's looking for.

Comment: Maybe this will help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/wrong-type-argument-commandp-error-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key

Comment: `compile` is a built in command.  You should probably name your new command `go-compile` or something.  But really all you need to do is set `compile-command` variable, look at its documentation.  Also, I use the package `multi-compile` to set the compile command based on major mode.